# Possible to show organization header next to names in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-client

This is a question for any (or all) Outlook versions, both the native client a the web interface.

For email messages that contain an `Organization` header, is it possible to show the content of this header ‘next’ to the sender's name in some way? (When viewing the message and/or in the message/conversation list.)

Comment: Best fit I could find is [RFC 1036](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1036) which would be related USENET. As it's probably an uncommon header I doubt it's possible with built-in tools. Are you able to write and use plugins/extensions?

Comment: @Seth You are right, the Organization field is not standardized for use in general email. (No, I don't think plugins/extensions are an option in my situation.) Should I delete the question because it is based on incorrect assumptions?

Comment: It could just as well be that I'm misunderstanding you. Is that the actual header you're talking about? As for whenever to delete or not, it's mostly up to you. Personally I'd let it stay in case someone else is looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that in either desktop client or OWA. In general, you can't select custom Internet headers to display if they're not in the "All ... Fields" when customizing the message list's view.